# Zend_Mail Could not open socket

Tags: zend-framework

i'm using Zend_Mail to send out an email from Aruba PEC.

```
    $config = array('auth'=>'login', 
                    'ssl' => 'ssl',
                    'port' => 465,
                    'username'=>'user@pec.it', 
                    'password'=>'pass');

    $tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('62.149.152.91',$config); 
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();

    $mail->setBodyHtml('Mail test');
    $mail->setFrom('user@pec.it');
    $mail->addTo('marco@email.it');
    $mail->setSubject('Test');
    $mail->send();
```

but i receive this error: " Could not open socket ".

Now if i try to exceute this script on my local pc it works correctly, but wen i try to exceute it on server in my local area network i receive this error.
than i i try with another ip address (no certifaction account) it works correctly.
(so i think that is a problem of configuration server??)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have OpenSSL installed on the PC. Is your server Windows? It is a bit of a pain if you are.

Comment: i'm on Iseries IBM I and i have OpenSSL installed

Comment: Have you checked your firewall? Are you going to deploy this application on that server or a different server?